# What does Flow not like about this code that conditionally accesses an object's property only if it exists

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Here's my code:

```
// @flow

var x = {a: 'foo'};
var key = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'b' : 'a';
var value = x.hasOwnProperty(key) ? x[key] : 'default';
console.log(value);
```

So `x[key]` is only accessed if `key` really is a property of `x`, otherwise a default value is used. But Flow does not like this, it says:

```
test-flow.js:5
  5: var value = x.hasOwnProperty(key) ? x[key] : 'default';
                                           ^^^ property `b`. Property not found in
  5: var value = x.hasOwnProperty(key) ? x[key] : 'default';
                                         ^ object literal
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's pretty clearly a failure of the tool.

Comment: Maybe, but there must be some canonical way to do "access object if key exists, otherwise return default"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Flow. You might want to open an issue on their [github](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues).

Meanwhile, adding an explicit type to `key` fixes the problem for some reason:

```
var key: string = ...
```

Comment: btw bug [still has](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2008) status of opened :(

Comment: `// Error
({foo:3}[('bar')])`

`// Magic
({foo:3}[('bar': string)]);`