# Flowtype error when trying to get object value via dynamic key

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a code that receives an object, iterates its keys and performs different actions based on particular key presence in another config object.

Here's an abstract example:

```
type InputObject = {
  foo: number,
  bar: number,
  baz: number,
};

const multipliers = {
  bar: 3,
};

function processData(data: InputObject) {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    const value = data[key];

    if (Object.keys(multipliers).indexOf(key) !== -1) {
      console.log(value * multipliers[key]);
    } else {
      console.log(value);
    }
  });
}
```

If I check this code with `flow check` command it gives the following errors:

> Cannot get multipliers[key] because:
>   • property baz is missing in object literal [1].
>   • property foo is missing in object literal [1].

Why Flow doesn't understand that `multipliers[key]` is executed only if `key` exists in `multipliers`?
Is there any way to fix the errors by changing type annotations without changing the code?

Comment: just for information: it seems flow does not understand `hasOwnProperty` [in similar case](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2008) so it means if will not understand `indexOf(key) !== -1` as well. [Type Refinements](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) docs article also has not helped :(

Comment: try answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897927/what-does-flow-not-like-about-this-code-that-conditionally-accesses-an-objects it's strange but there it helped

Comment: @JuanMendes I don't know. Just wrote it mechanically. Your variant indeed more readable and preferable but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: That's why it's a comment, I didn't really think it would fix it. Though it does seem that simpler check like `in` could be added eventually

Comment: @skyboyer thanks a lot for the reference to that question! It's really strange but the errors disappeared after I've added type definition to the `key` parameter in the callback function.

Answer (score -1):

Flow is correct in that your object of type InputObject has three required fields vs multipliers has just one field bar. The key is referring to a key of type InputObject. 
One way is to cast key as a new string and use that as a reference to lookup. This does however make flow lose reference to key's type which is why `$Keys<InputObject>` makes sense to ensure stronger typing.

```
type InputObject = {
  foo: number,
  bar: number,
  baz: number
}

const multipliers = {
  bar: 3,
}

function processData(data: inputObject) {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key: $Keys<InputObject> => {
    const value = data[key];
    const lookupKey = String(key);
    if (multipliers.hasOwnProperty(lookupKey)) {
      console.log(value * multipliers[lookupKey]);
    else {
      console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: `const lookupKey = String(key);` - this line do the real magic
`// Error
({foo:3}[('bar')])

// Magic
({foo:3}[(String('bar'))]);`